# function CHECK mysql

Tags: mysql, sql

Why this constraint doesn't work?

I need if gender is Male then name doesn't start with 'Ms.'

```
CREATE TABLE moviestar
  ( name varchar(30) PRIMARY KEY,
    gender char(1),
    CONSTRAINT chk_movie CHECK(gender = 'F' AND name  NOT LIKE 'Ms.%')
  );
```

Comment: MySQL does not support `check` right now. Whatever you define will be ignored.

Comment: so what's the use of check in mysql? Is it useless? And what's the difference between simple CHECK and Constraint check?

Comment: It is useless currently but may be implemented in a future version of MySQL.

Comment: @user3238724: the MySQL "way" is to prevent error message at all costs. Un-implemented features are often silently ignored (to make the SQL "compatible" with other dialects) rather than complaining that the SQL is not supported.

Answer (score 1):

**The [MySQL Reference Manual](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/create-table.html) says:**

The CHECK clause is parsed but ignored by all storage engines.

Try to build your own business logic using triggers !

Comment: Thank you, I just watched this example in one tutorial of oracle and tried it in MySQL.